# French animated movie with talking cat and missing scientists

Tags: story-identification, movie

About a year and a half ago, my friend showed me this movie and it was in French. All I can remember was there there was a talking cat and this black cloud that took people away to some fort or something.

Also, I think there might've been lizard people, I honestly don't know.

The movie was animated, and in a steampunk era I believe.

Answer (score 12):

*Avril et le monde truqué* (*April and the extraordinary world*, 2015)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3422078/):

> In 1941, the world is radically different from the one we know from history books. Geopolitics has developed strangely: Napoleon V rules France and, for the last 70 years, scholars have been mysteriously disappearing, depriving mankind of their inventions. Without radio, television, electricity, aviation, and the combustion engine, the world is mired in outdated technology, dozing in the previous century's knowhow dominated by coal and steam. In this bizarre universe, Avril (Marion Cotillard), a teenage girl, Darwin (Philippe Katerine), her talking cat, Pops (Jean Rochefort), her grandfather, and Julius (Marc-André Grondin), a young scoundrel and police informer, go off in search of Avril's parents, two of the missing scientists. The quartet will face many dangers and mysteries in this strange new Rigged World.

---

Found with the Google query `film francais chat qui parle nuage noir scientifiques` (`french movie talking cat black cloud scientists`) which returned [the movie's page on Allociné](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=224355.html), the main French site about cinema.

Comment: Oh my gosh, this is it. Thank you so much for helping me. My friend will be happy to know I was able to find it.

Comment: @TheShekiah you're welcome, enjoy the re-watch! If you want, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left. :)